# How to model shared folders in ElasticSearch or SOLR?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, acl, rbac

Popular search engines are quite performant when it comes to full text searches and many other aspects, however, I am not sure how to map the main document storage system security policies to ES and/or SOLR?

Consider Google Drive and it's folders. Users can share any folder - then files and folders below are also shared. Content management systems use something similar.

But how to map that to the external search engines (that is, not built-in to application's content management system), especially, if there are millions of documents in many tens of thousands of folders, tens of thousands of users? Will it help if, for example, depth (nestedness) of the folders is limited to some small number?

I know ES has user roles, but I can't see it can help here, because accesses are given more or less arbitrary. Another approach is to somehow materialize user access in the documents (folders and documents) themselves, but then changes in users' roles, local to some folder, will result in changing many thousands of documents.

Also, searches can be quite arbitrary and lengthy, so it is desired to have pagination, so, for example, fetching "everything" and then sorting out user access on application side is not an option.

I believe the scenario described is quite common, but I can't find any hints how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had used solr as search engine and solr's Data Import Handler (DIH) feature for importing the data from database to Solr.

I would suggest you to go with the approach of indexing the acl's along with the documents.

I had done the same approach and its working fine till now.

I agree that you have re-index the data on the solr side when there is any changes on folder access or change in the access of level of documents. We do need to re-index the document if the metadata of the document is changes or the content of the document is changes. Similarly we can also update the documents on the solr side for any changes in the ACL(Access Control List).

Why to index the ACL along with Document information.
The reason is whenever user search for a document, you can pass the user acl as part of the query in the form of filter query and get the documents which are accessible to user.
I feel this removes the complexity of applying the acl logic at the back end side.

If you dont index the ACL in solr, then you have to filter out the documents after you retrieve from solr by checking the document is and whatever the acl logic applies.

Or the last option could be index the document without acls. Let the user search all the documents. When he tries to perform any action on those documents then you can check the permission and allow the user to perform the action or deny the user saying you dont have enough permission to access the document.

Action could be like View, Download, Update etc..

You need to decide whichever approach suits and works out in your case.

Comment: So you are suggesting to materialize ACLs info on every change for a user OR an asset to potentially lots of documents? Have you tried it in practice?

Comment: yes...I am suggesting index the acl along with documents and for every update you can re-index the data...Have done this for our product...working fine ...reindexing is not done immediately...but done after every 4 hours...