# Check user access to data in solr

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, solr, search-engine

I have a sql database with a complex structure of tables that are storing the data (text and file) of my application alongside my users' information and their access to the data. Also in order to add search capability to my application I have created a solr index that stores a flat structure of data points. But the data of users' access to the data points is only stored in the sql db. The logic of data access is fairly complex.
I have thousands of documents in solr and I want to have pagination capability. What is the best practice for querying solr but only returning data that a user has access to? Should I move the logic of user access to solr? Is there any alternative?

Comment: How many users or groups have access to each resource? Can you index a field that contains user ids or group ids that have access to the resource? (there are also a few talks about this problem in the Solr/Lucene Revolution talks archives, you might want to search through that on Youtube)

Comment: It's possible but as I said the business logic of checking if a user has access or not is complex and I guess duplicating it in solr would be messy and could cause issues. I appreciate it if you could provide any link to the youtube video about this topic.

Comment: check if this is of any help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64686242/how-to-model-shared-folders-in-elasticsearch-or-solr/64691703#64691703